# Is this php smarty template statement a security flaw?

Tags: php

```
$smarty->assign("action", $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
```

`PHP_SELF` is set client side by the browser so it can be modified by an attacker. Is Smarty "action" assigned to the form action field? 
So can an attacker control where to POST data is sent, or see the variables set on the server side?

Any other flaws with this statement?

Comment: The problem with "are there any flaws with this system" questions asked here, is: The answer can only be either "Yes!" or "probably..."  This is not a peer reviewed journal; we are not the top experts (well, many of us aren't the top experts; myself included)... and most importantly, we haven't spent thousands of hours investigating your system. The question, as it is now, states that you know of a security flaw. That's where most of us stop and try to find alternatives; not where we say "eeeehhhhhhhhh, maybe we can get away with this and hope no malicious people notice."

Comment: That is...  Does it really matter to you whether or not there are other security flaws with this?  You identified one, and unless you're doing a full risk analysis, that's enough for me.

Comment: A user can always change where to send the post data, and can inspect and change any part of it before posting. What is the attack vector for this? You generally don't have to stop a user from hacking themselves, only from hacking the server or other users

Comment: @Ghedipunk You are assuming one security flaw is already found. I think that is what OP asks - is this a security flaw?

Comment: @Anders, "Any other flaws" implies that they consider this a security flaw.  As we can't see the rest of their application, we can only trust OP's judgement.  (And yes, Smarty allows additional customization that could potentially allow un-validated and unsanitized user generated content to cause some very serious XSS or server-side issues, that we can't tell from their snippet).

Answer (score 1):

The traditional problem with using `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` is that it includes `PATH_INFO` after the script URI. This means the URL can include dangerous characters which can lead to cross site scripting, f.ex if you script was `script.php` an attacker could append data after it like this:
`https://example.com/script.php/thispart/is_path_info/"><script>alert(1)</script>`

However as `PATH_INFO` is a configurable option for your web server, exploitation may not be possible. It is also possible to escape variables via smarty using [escaping](https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.escape) to prevent this.